# panel not showing sencha touch 2

Tags: extjs, view, touch, panels

I'm trying to switch panels when tapping 'login' in a toolbar.
My controller gets the event and I switch by adding and setting the active item to the panel I want.. however, the screen stays blank (and there are no debug errors).

This is the code of my panel, any idea what the mistake might be?

```
Ext.define('App.view.LoginView', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'loginpanel',
alias: 'widget.loginView',

fullscreen: true,
layout: 'fit',

items: [
    {
        xtype: 'TopToolBar'
    },
    {
            xtype: 'formpanel',
            items: [
            {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Login',
                instructions: 'Have a great day!',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'emailfield',
                        name: 'email',
                        label: 'Email'
                    },

                    {
                        xtype: 'passwordfield',
                        name: 'password',
                        label: 'Password'
                    }
                ]
            },

            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Login',
                ui: 'confirm',
                handler: function()
                {
                    this.up('loginpanel').submit();
                }
            }
        ]
    }]})
```

The code of my toolbar class:

```
Ext.define('App.view.TopToolBar', {
extend: 'Ext.Toolbar',
xtype: 'TopToolBar',
dock: 'top',
initialize: function() {
    var loginButton = {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Login',
        ui: 'action',
        handler: this.onLoginTap,
        scope: this
    };

    this.add(loginButton);
},

onLoginTap: function(){
    console.log('login tap');
    this.fireEvent('loginBtnHandler', this);
}})
```

Comment: When does the screen go blank? When you push the button or when you try to execute the code? It looks like you only define classes and not instanciate them.

Comment: indeed, that was the problem, i did not instanciate them ;) thx! (i also had to give layouts to the components)

Comment: shall I answer the question so you can accept it? Its better for you, this site and for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define classes with [`Ext.define`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext-method-define).

```
Ext.define('My.Toolbar', {
    extend: 'Ext.Toolbar',
    alias: 'widget.mytoolbar'
    //configuration
});
```

Create(Instantiate) classes with [`Ext.create`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext-method-create)

```
var tlb= Ext.create('My.Toolbar', {
    //configuration
});
```